# Print something in PHP built-in web server

Tags: php, embeddedwebserver

In python built-in web server when use `print` in function, it prints result in terminal ...

for example:

```
Django version 1.3.4, using settings 'parsicore.settings'
Development server is running at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
Using the Werkzeug debugger (http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/)
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.


127.0.0.1 - - [16/Jan/2013 02:02:08] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
hello ... print 1 2 3
```

How can I print something like this in PHP built-in web server?

for example I want print $_POST in terminal. I use `php -S 127.0.0.1:3000` for run PHP built-in web server.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The [development web server built in to PHP 5.4+](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) does not work in the way you want.  That is, it's not a PHP process, and you can't have it run code for you.

It's designed to serve PHP applications and content from the specified directory.  The output of the server process is the *access log*.  You *can* write to the log using the [`error_log`](http://php.net/error_log) function, with a value of 4 as the `message_type`.  So, in theory, you could do something like

```
ob_start();
var_dump($_POST);
error_log(ob_get_clean(), 4);
```

It sounds like you're trying to perform some debugging.  You should be using [real debugging tools](http://xdebug.org/) instead of cobbling something together.

Comment: I share you opinion, that nothing can replace real debugging, but writing the logs to the console, instead of a file, in a development setup sounds interesting too.

Answer (score 46):

Just pipe your data to error_log():

```
error_log(print_r($_REQUEST, true));
```

Answer (score 9):

php built-in server writes output to the `php://stdout` stream , which mean you can output anything to it, but this should only be used for debugging.

here's a quick example of how can you achieve the result of writing to the server console :

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);


/**
 * This is for development purpose ONLY !
 */
final class ServerLogger {

    /**
     * send a log message to the STDOUT stream.
     *
     * @param array<int, mixed> $args
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public static function log(...$args): void {
        foreach ($args as $arg) {
            if (is_object($arg) || is_array($arg) || is_resource($arg)) {
                $output = print_r($arg, true);
            } else {
                $output = (string) $arg;
            }

            fwrite(STDOUT, $output . "\n");
         }
    }
}

// usage example : 
ServerLogger::log('Hello, world!');
// outputting an array : 
ServerLogger::log($_SERVER);
```

Comment: It was exactly what I was looking for !

Comment: this function is throwin ´ErrorException (E_WARNING)
Use of undefined constant STDOUT - assumed 'STDOUT' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)´ in php 7.4

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
// PHP 7.4 and up

define('STDOUT', fopen('php://stdout', 'w'));
fwrite(STDOUT, print_r($_REQUEST, true));
```

Comment: In order to add more value to your answer please consider to add some proper explanation to it [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/29706767)