# Laravel - Service Provider - Bind multiple classes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I know how to bind a single class:

```
public function register() {
    $this->app->bind('search', 'Laracasts\Search\Search');
}
```

But imagine my `Laracasts\Search\` dir having these files:

- Search.php // class Search
- SearchX.php // class SearchX
- SearchY.php // class SearchY
- SearchZ.php // class SearchZ

What is the best way to bind these four files/classes into the search facade?

I read in another [non-related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28290332/best-practices-for-custom-helpers-on-laravel-5/28360186#comment47536515_28360186) that we can use a mapper. But how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a separate binding for each class/facade:

```
public function register() {
    $this->app->bind('search.x', 'Laracasts\Search\SearchX');
    $this->app->bind('search.y', 'Laracasts\Search\SearchY');
    ...
}
```

A binding can only be bound to one thing. Of course, within the bound class, you can do anything you like:

```
public function register() {
    $this->app->bind('search.all', 'Laracasts\Search\SearchAll');
}

class SearchAll() {

    private $searchers = []; // an array of searchers

    // Use Laravel Dependency Injection to instantiate our searcher classes
    public function __construct(SearchX $searchX, SearchY $searchY) {
        $this->searchers = [$searchX, $searchY];
    }

    public function search($value) {
        $matches = [];
        foreach ($this->searchers() as $searcher) {
            $matches += $searchers->search();
        }
        return $matches;
    }
}

// elsewhere in your app...
$searcher = app('search.all');
$matches = $searcher->search('hello');
```