# Laravel Bind Multiple Class to One Contract in The Service Provider

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

So what I am trying to do is have my eccomerce site handle both Paypal and Stripe payments. However, I am not sure how this is done.

This is what I have.

```html
class BillingProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('App\Contracts\BillingInterface','App\Services\Billing\PaypalBilling');
    }
}
```

This works fine if I only need Paypal. However, I need both Paypal and Stripe.

Any idea how we can go about implementing this? So when we typehint this we can either get paypal or stripe.

```
public function stripe(Request $request, BillingInterface $bill){// Handle stripe payment.}

public function paypal(Request $request, BillingInterface $bill){// Handle paypal payment.}
```

Comment: If the stripe() and paypal() methods are in the same class and you're trying to inject a different dependency object depending on the `BillingInterface`, you can just use `$this->app->make('PayPalClass')` inside the method and not use the DI.

Comment: Don't use the Container resolution, instantiate and pass the instance manually.

Comment: Some links to look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31887870/laravel-service-provider-bind-multiple-classes  https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/multiple-services-implementing-same-interface-switching-at-runtime

Answer (score 1):

Imho, there are many ways to do it.

First of all, take a look to the [contextual binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/container#contextual-binding) of the Service Container. If you're using different classes on your checkout procedure, you can set a resolve strategy based on who is actually using the contract.

However, I would probably choose something different.

Let's apply the [strategy design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) for this.

Basically, in two separate steps:

- create a "top" class named, for example, `BillingManager`;
- a class for each payment type (imho, make a `paypal()` and a `stripe()` method in a single class is wrong [because of this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)) that implement your billing interface. Let's say that this interface has a 'process($orderId)` method;

Now, the `BillingManager` class will be called. Probably, you will call a general method `pay` that will take, as a parameter, something to understand what strategy it will use.

Something like

```
public function pay($strategy, $orderId) {
    // use $strategy to understand which service must be used.
    // very raw example:

    $strategy = app()->make($strategy . 'Strategy');
    $strategy->process($orderId);
}
```

Of course, you will need a safe mechanism to understand what service you will need to use. After that, you will be able to use the `BillingManager` class every time, with many different payment systems, without worry about anything else.