# How do I make global helper functions in laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade, controllers, helper

If I wanted to make a `currentUser()` function for some oauth stuff I am doing where I can use it in a view or in a controller (think rails, where you do `helper_method: current_user` in the application controller).

Everything I read states to create a helpers folder and add the function there and then that way you can do `Helpers::functionName` Is this the right way to do this?

Whats the "laravel way" of creating helper functions that can be used in blade templates and controllers?

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28290332/best-practices-for-custom-helpers-on-laravel-5

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Create a new file in your app/Helpers directory name it AnythingHelper.php
An example of my helper is :

```
<?php
function getDomesticCities()
{
$result = \App\Package::where('type', '=', 'domestic')
    ->groupBy('from_city')
    ->get(['from_city']);

return $result;
}
```

generate a service provider for your helper by following command

```
php artisan make:provider HelperServiceProvider
```

in the register function of your newly generated HelperServiceProvider.php add following code

```
require_once app_path('Helpers/AnythingHelper.php');
```

now in your config/app.php load this service provider and you are done

```
'App\Providers\HelperServiceProvider',
```

Comment: How do you use this in blade. Do you need to register facade?

Comment: No, only above mentioned code does it, in your blade file do {{ yourHelperFunction('param') }}

Comment: I wish I can call the helper function with Helper::myHelperFunction('param') in blade. It looks nicer. Do you know how to register this ?

Comment: I dont think you access facades in blade, and if you can (by tweaking something) I am not sure whether it is a good practice

Comment: I added alias/facade in config/app like: 'Helper' => App\Helpers\Helper::class, and I'm able to use the Helper::myHelperFunction('param') in blade.

Comment: Thank you. Not sure if it isn't good practice. I saw many people use it. It just look nicer than having global function that would clash with the built in PHP function. Like time() function. So, it's the best that we use like this MyHelper::time() in blade;

Comment: lol @ looks nicer. Facades are NOT nicer - and in most cases, bad practice to use them.

Comment: `require base_path().'/app/Helpers/AnythingHelper.php';` doesn't work for me with error Failed opening required

Comment: AnythingHelper.php is just an example, you should replace this with original file name

Comment: @KhanShahrukh use ```require_once base_path().'/app/Helpers/AnythingHelper.php';```

If you use ```require``` phpunit will fail.

Comment: You should supply the path as an argument to base_path(). Instead: base_path() . '/my/helper.php'; Better use: base_path('/my/helper.php'). Also app_path() would be more suitable ;)

Comment: In `Lumen`  we have to include in this fashion `require_once base_path('app').'/Helpers/AnythingHelper.php';`

Comment: Don't forget to define `public static function` otherwise you will get error, something like this `Non-static method App\Helpers\GlobalHelper::getValueFromGlobalHelper() should not be called statically`

Answer (score 62):

An easy and efficient way of creating a global functions file is to autoload it directly from Composer. The autoload section of composer accepts a `files` array that is automatically loaded.

1. Create a `functions.php` file wherever you like. In this example, we are going to create in inside `app/Helpers`.
2. Add your functions, but do ***not*** add a class or namespace.

   ```
   <?php

   function global_function_example($str)
   {
      return 'A Global Function with '. $str;
   }
   ```
3. In `composer.json` inside the `autoload` section add the following line:

   ```
   "files": ["app/Helpers/functions.php"]
   ```

   Example for Laravel 5:

   ```
   "autoload": {
       "classmap": [
           "database"
       ],
       "psr-4": {
           "App\\": "app/"
       },
       "files": ["app/Helpers/functions.php"] // <-- Add this line
   },
   ```
4. Run `composer dump-autoload`

Done! You may now access `global_function_example('hello world')` form any part of your application including Blade views.

Comment: I also need to create a global function where can be called in multiple controller files. This looks simple but what happens when run the command `composer dump-autoload`? Are new files been created? I even deleted the files like composer.json, gulpfile.js as I didn't think they were used at all.

Comment: Great! Running `composer dump-autoload` would be similar to clearing the composer cache. Basically, it re-evaluates the classes that need to be loaded from composer.json file. Good luck!

Comment: Efficient method

Comment: much straightforward than the accepted answer. I tried both!

Comment: Love this implementation. Straight forward and faster!

Comment: If the item is not last don't forget the comma after "files": ["app/Helpers/functions.php"], and for mac the command will be composer.phar dump-autoload

Answer (score 25):

## Laravel global helpers

Often you will find your self in need of a utility function that is access globally throughout you entire application. Borrowing from how laravel writes their default helpers you're able to extend the ability with your custom functions.

### Create the helper **file**, not class

I prefer to you a file and not a class since I dont want to bother with namespaces and I want its functions to be accessible without the class prefixes like: `greeting('Brian');` instead of `Helper::greeting('Brian');` just like Laravel does with their helpers.

**File:** `app/Support/helper.php`

### Register helper file with Composer: `composer.json`

```
{
    ...
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "files": [
            "app/Support/helpers.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    ...
}
```

### Create your first helper function

```
<?php

if (!function_exists('greet')) {
    /**
     * Greeting a person
     *
     * @param  string $person Name
     * @return string
     */
    function greet($person)
    {
        return 'Hello ' . $person;
    }
}
```

### Usage:

Remember to autoload the file before trying to access its functions:
`composer dump-autoload`

#### Let's test with **Tinker**

```
$ php artisan tinker
Psy Shell v0.8.17 (PHP 7.0.6 ΓÇö cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> greet('Brian');
=> "Hello Brian"
>>> exit
Exit:  Goodbye.
```

#### With **Blade**

```
<p>{{ greet('Brian') }}</p>
```

#### Advanced usage as Blade directive:

A times you will find yourself wanting to use a blade directive instead of a plain function.
Register you Blade directive in the boot method of AppServiceProvider: `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`

```
public function boot()
{
    // ...
    Blade::directive('greet', function ($expression) {
        return "<?php echo greet({$expression}); ?>";
    });
}
```

**Usage:** 
`<p>@greet('Brian')</p>`

**Note:** you might need to clear cache views
`php artisan view:clear`

Comment: I had to do a composer dump-autoload for it to work

Answer (score 6):

The above answers are great with a slight complication, therefore this answer exists.

**utils.php**

```
if (!function_exists('printHello')) {

    function printHello()
    {
        return "Hello world!";
    }
}
```

in **app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php** add the following in **register** method

```
public function register()
{
   require_once __DIR__ . "/path/to/utils.php"
}
```

now **printHello** function is accessible anywhere in code-base just as any other laravel global functions.

Answer (score 5):

Another option, if you don't want to register all your helper functions one by one and wondering how to register them each time you create a new helper function:

Again in the **app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php** add the following in **register** method

```
public function register()
{
    foreach (glob(app_path().'/Helpers/*.php') as $filename) {
        require_once($filename);
    }
}
```