# calling a php function that is outside the controller using laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

so I have this function that gets the remaining memory where my Laravel project is located. The thing is there are two controllers that need to check the remaining memory.

Here is what it looks like it is just inside my controller

```
private function convGB($bytes, $unit = "", $decimals = 2)
{
     $units = array('B' => 0, 'KB' => 1, 'MB' => 2, 'GB' => 3, 'TB' => 4, 
     'PB' => 5, 'EB' => 6, 'ZB' => 7, 'YB' => 8);

     $value = 0;
     if ($bytes > 0) 
     {
         if (!array_key_exists($unit, $units)) 
         {
             $pow = floor(log($bytes)/log(1024));
             $unit = array_search($pow, $units);
         }

         $value = ($bytes/pow(1024,floor($units[$unit])));
     }

     if (!is_numeric($decimals) || $decimals < 0) {
     $decimals = 2;
     }

     return sprintf('%.' . $decimals . 'f '.$unit, $value);
}

private function getMem()
{
    $ds  = disk_total_space(substr(base_path(), 0, 2));
    $fs  = disk_free_space(substr(base_path(), 0, 2));
    $ffs = disk_free_space(substr(base_path(), 0, 2));

    if ($ds >= 1073741824)
    {
        $ds = number_format($ds / 1073741824, 2) . ' GB';
    }
    elseif ($ds >= 1048576)
    {
        $ds = number_format($ds / 1048576, 2) . ' MB';
    }
    elseif ($ds >= 1024)
    {
        $ds = number_format($ds / 1024, 2) . ' KB';
    }
    elseif ($ds > 1)
    {
        $ds = $ds . ' B';
    }
    elseif ($ds == 1)
    {
        $ds = $ds . ' B';
    }
    else
    {
        $ds = '0 size';
    }

    if ($fs >= 1073741824)
    {
        $fs = number_format($fs / 1073741824, 2) . ' GB';
    }
    elseif ($fs >= 1048576)
    {
        $fs = number_format($fs / 1048576, 2) . ' MB';
    }
    elseif ($fs >= 1024)
    {
        $fs = number_format($fs / 1024, 2) . ' KB';
    }
    elseif ($fs > 1)
    {
        $fs = $fs . ' B';
    }
    elseif ($fs == 1)
    {
        $fs = $fs . ' B';
    }
    else
    {
        $fs = '0 size';
    }

    $converted = $this->convGB($ffs);

    return array( $ds , $fs , $converted);
}
```

So I wanted to put the function in an external PHP so that I would just call it when I needed it. Any ideas on how to do this? Thanks so much!

Comment: So which function do you want to move? I see two in your code example.

Comment: hi i will just use the `getMem` function

Answer (score 1):

Create a new file in your app/Helpers directory name it AnythingHelper.php An example of my helper is :

```
<?php
function getDomesticCities()
{
$result = \App\Package::where('type', '=', 'domestic')
    ->groupBy('from_city')
    ->get(['from_city']);

return $result;
}
```

generate a service provider for your helper by following command

```
php artisan make:provider HelperServiceProvider
```

in the register function of your newly generated HelperServiceProvider.php add following code

```
require base_path().'/app/Helpers/AnythingHelper.php';
```

now in your config/app.php load this service provider and you are done

```
'App\Providers\HelperServiceProvider',
```

The code was taken from here: [How do I make global helper functions in laravel 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32419619/how-do-i-make-global-helper-functions-in-laravel-5)