# how to create global function that can be accessed from any controller and blade file

Tags: laravel, controller, global

I have two controller file homecontroller and backendcontroller. What is the best way to create global function and access it from both files?

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32419619/how-do-i-make-global-helper-functions-in-laravel-5) Arian Acosta's answer helpful but I wonder if there is an easiest way. I would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

**Updated:**

**Step 1**
Add folder inside app folder
**app->Helper**

**Step 2**
add php Class inside Helper folder
**Eg. Helper.php**

Add namespace and class to the Helper.php

```
namespace App\Helper;

class Helper
{

}
```

Register this Helper.php into config/app.php file

```
'aliases' => [
       ....
       'Helper' => App\Helper\Helper::class
 ]
```

Now, write all the functions inside **Helper.php** and it will be accessible everywhere.

**How to access from Controller?**

Step 1 - Add a namespace at top of the controller.

```
use App\Helper\Helper;
```

Step 2 - Call function - Assume there a **getInformation()** inside the Helper Class.

```
$information = Helper::getInformation()
```

Comment: Hi Rahul. This worked for me. I choose the answer as an accepted answer as I think this is the easiest way to do this.

Comment: where do you make the file? is it anywhere?

Comment: @Rahul your answer is not complete. Please update it so that user can know what is path of common.php file. Thanks.

Comment: is there a way I can make that method to run automatically in the controller, without having to explicitly calling it?

Comment: how do you acces helper function using an alias?

Comment: how do I call a helper function from a controller?

Comment: add a namespace to the controller. Eg. if the class name is Helper.

use App\Library\Helper;

public function getData() {
Helper::getInformation();
}

Comment: How to use the helper function in Lumen 8.0? Please share your views. Thanks a lot.

Comment: How can i access in Blade file ?

Answer (score 85):

### Easy Solution:

1. Create a new `Helpers` folder under the `app` folder.
2. Create a `.php` file named `helper_functions.php` in the `Helpers` folder.
3. Add your PHP function(s) to `helper_functions.php`

   ```
   //Examples
   function function_a($params){       
       //add your code
   } 

   function function_b($params){        
       //add your code
   }
   ```
4. Add `helper_functions.php` path to the `Files` section of `composer.json`:

   ```
   "autoload": {
       ...
       "files": [
           "app/Helpers/your_helper_function.php"
       ]
       ...
   }
   ```
5. Refresh Composer autoload files. (Run this in your project directory)

   ```
   composer dump-autoload
   ```

That's it! you can access `function_a()` or `function_b()` in any part of your Laravel project.

---

**I also have a blog post that covers the same topic:**

[How to Add a Global Function in Laravel Using Composer?](https://www.kerneldev.com/2017/12/05/how-to-add-a-global-function-in-laravel-using-composer/)

Comment: Hi Sapnesh. what the command `composer dump-autoload` really does? Does it create new files?

Comment: @hijacker83 When your project is run the composer loads some files into memory, for seamless coding experience (no namespace hassle and all) so whenever you make any changes to the `composer.json` file (which composer uses to auto load dependencies) you should run `composer dump-autoload` which will dump currently loaded files and load according to the changed config file. It's just good practice to avoid problems

Comment: Thanks for the method.

Comment: I think it's the best way to do that

Comment: If you are working with big team or you are planning for feature, it is not recommended way, because it can be a "magical" methods. Other developers can spend plenty time to understand how magic method comes in. For my opinion, the Helpers way are much more better (with config/app.php).

Comment: /!\ This method imply the file NOT TO BE NAMESPACED. Want to add this little warning since I was playing around with both (main) solutions explained here and ended up with a namespace in my autoloaded file.

Answer (score 84):

## Solution

One way to do this is to create a class and use its instance, this way you can not only access the object of the class within a controller, blade, or any other class as well.

## AppHelper file

In you app folder create a folder named **Helpers** and within it create a file name **AppHelper** or any of your choice

```
<?php
namespace App\Helpers;

class AppHelper
{
      public function bladeHelper($someValue)
      {
             return "increment $someValue";
      }

     public function startQueryLog()
     {
           \DB::enableQueryLog();
     }

     public function showQueries()
     {
          dd(\DB::getQueryLog());
     }

     public static function instance()
     {
         return new AppHelper();
     }
}
```

## Usage

### In a controller

When in a controller you can call the various functions

```
public function index()
{
    //some code

   //need to debug query
   \App\Helpers\AppHelper::instance()->startQueryLog();

   //some code that executes queries
   \App\Helpers\AppHelper::instance()->showQueries();
}
```

### In a blade file

Say you were in a blade file, here is how you can call the app blade helper function

```
some html code
{{ \App\Helpers\AppHelper::instance()->bladeHelper($value) }}
and then some html code
```

### Reduce the overhead of namespace (Optional)

You can also reduce the overhead of call the complete function namespace **\App\Helpers** by creating alias for the **AppHelper** class in **config\app.php**

```
'aliases' => [
       ....
       'AppHelper' => App\Helpers\AppHelper::class
 ]
```

and in your controller or your blade file, you can directly call

```
\AppHelper::instance()->functioName();
```

Comment: hi! it seems very advanced for me. Do I need to use always use `public static function instance()  {  return new AppHelper();  }` then call any function with `\App\Helpers\AppHelper::instance()->functionname();` ?

Comment: You can remove instance function and make all the other functions static functions and make direct call **AppHelper::bladeHelper()**. The instance function helps me to initialize things in constructor or chain function calls.

Comment: just me or do you need to do a `composer dump-autoload` for  Laravel to recognize the new file?

Comment: This proposal is inefficient because it creates a new instance of a class every time `instance` is called. Moreover, it seems that the "global" functions are completely unrelated to each other and don't use anything which requires a "this"-object. So there is absolutely no reason why they should be part of the same class. This seems to be a complete misuse of the concept of OOP and is simply bad coding style.

Answer (score 17):

## The Laravel Service Provider way

I've been using global function within Laravel for a while and I want to share how I do it. It's kind of a mix between 2 answers in this post : https://stackoverflow.com/a/44021966/5543999 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/44024328/5543999

This way will load a file within a ServiceProvider and register it within your Laravel app.

Where is the difference, the scope, it's always about the scope.

```
Composer //Autload whitin composer.json method
|
|--->Laravel App //My method
     |
     |--->Controller //Trait method
     |--->Blade //Trait method
     |--->Listener //Trait method
     |--->...
```

This is a really simplist way to explain my point, all three methods will achieve the purpose of the "Global function". The Traits method will need you to declare `use App\Helpers\Trait;` or `App\Helpers\Trait::function()`.

The composer and service provider are almost about the same. For me, they answer better to the question of what is a global function, because they don't require to declare them on each place you want to use them. You just use them `function()`. The main difference is how you prefer things.

### How to

1. Create the functions file : App\Functions\GlobalFunctions.php

   ```
   //App\Functions\GlobalFunctions.php
   <?php

       function first_function()
       {
           //function logic
       }

       function second_function()
       {
           //function logic
       }
   ```
2. Create a ServiceProvider:

   ```
    //Into the console
    php artisan make:provider GlobalFunctionsServiceProvider
   ```
3. Open the new file App\Providers\GlobalFunctionsServiceProvider.php and edit the register method

   ```
    //App\Providers\GlobalFunctionsServiceProvider.php

    public function register()
    {
        require_once base_path().'/app/Functions/GlobalFunctions.php';
    }
   ```
4. Register your provider into App\Config\App.php wihtin the providers

   ```
    //App\Config\App.php

    'providers' => [

        /*
        * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
        */
        Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        ...
        Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\GlobalFunctionsServiceProvider::class, //Add your service provider
   ```
5. Run some artisan's commands

   ```
    //Into the console
    php artisan clear-compiled
    php artisan config:cache
   ```
6. Use your new global functions

   ```
    //Use your function anywhere within your Laravel app
    first_function();
    second_function();
   ```

Answer (score 10):

In your `Controller.php` which `extends BaseController`, you can create a function like;

```
public function data($arr = false)
{
 $data['foo'] = 'bar';
 return array_merge($data,$arr);
}
```

And from any controller when you send a data to a view;

```
public function example()
{
 $data['smthg'] = 'smthgelse';
 return view('myView',$this->data($data));
}
```

The data in the the main controller can be accessed from all controllers and blades.

Comment: I use that solution, but the function doesn't work in `__construct` function. But, I think it's a simple and clear way to do that.

Comment: It is a bad practice to define functions that are unrelated to standard MVC operations inside controller. Would be wise to put them in a service.

Answer (score 4):

Laravel uses namespaces by default. So you need to follow the method described in that answer to setup a helper file.

Though in your case you want to access a method in different controllers. For this there's a simpler way. Add a method to you base controller `app/Http/Controllers/Controller.php` and you can access them in every other controller since they extend it.

```
// in app/Http/Controllers/Controller.php
protected function dummy()
{
    return 'dummy';
}

// in homecontroller

$this->dummy();
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways, depending on the exact functionality you're trying to add.

1) Create a function inside Controller.php, and make all other controller extend that controller. You could somewhat compair this to the master.blade.php

2) Create a trait, a trait can do a lot for you, and keeping ur controllers clean. I personally love to use traits as it will look clean, keep my Controller.php from being a mess with tons of different lines of code.

Comment: first time I heard about the trait. I found useful article here https://www.conetix.com.au/blog/simple-guide-using-traits-laravel-5 thank you very much.

Comment: @hijacker83 You are welcome, I would recommend having a good look into this, it will keep your code much cleaner than making 1 file having a ton of different functions that will become a mess.

Answer (score 0):

**Creating a global function**

create a Helpers.php file under a folder, let's name it 'core'.

```
core
 |
  -- Helpers.php


namespace Helpers; // define Helper scope

if(!function_exists('html')) {

  function html($string) {

    // run some code
    
    return $str;

  }

}
```

In your composer.json

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        
    },
    "files": [
        "core/Helpers.php"
    ]
}
```

in the file that you want to use it

```
// the " use " statement is not needed, core/Helpers is loaded on every page

  if(condition_is_true) {

   echo Helpers\html($string);die(); 

  }
```

Remove the namespace in Helpers.php if you want to call your function without the need to prefix namespace. However I advise to leave it there.

Credit: https://dev.to/kingsconsult/how-to-create-laravel-8-helpers-function-global-function-d8n

Answer (score 0):

By using composer.json and put the function containing file(globalhelper.php) to the autoload > files section, then run

> composer dump-autoload

You can access the function inside the file(globalhelper.php) without having to calling the class name, just like using default php function.

[image: composer.json 's autoload section]