# laravel 7 , blade file can not find function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I have inherited some legacy code and I am trying to get it to work on a dev server. It works fine on the prod server. I am a laravel noob.

I have almost everything working. (I have locked all the versions in composer.json, to match the working site)

The last thing that is failing is this line :

`<img src="{{ asset(GetProfilePicLanding())}}" class="img-responsive">`

I get the error`Call to undefined function GetProfilePicLanding()`

The blade file is in `resources/views/index.blade.php`

The function GetProfilePicLanding() is in `app/helper.php`

I can not imagine why the two servers running same code would be different in finding this file

I was looking at adding something like @include('app/helper') but then i have to modify the conf/view file.

I am trying not to modify the code itself if possible from prod.

Would love any ideas or how best to debug this.

thanks for any help

Comment: try running php artisan config:cache . The above requires a change to app/config, any changes to config, this artisan command usually needs a run after changing. Explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44021662/how-to-create-global-function-that-can-be-accessed-from-any-controller-and-blade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your helper.php file looks something like this:

```php
<?php

if (!function_exists('helper1')) {
    function helper1($string)
    {
        return ...;
    }
}

if (!function_exists('helper2')) {
    function helper2()
    {
        return ...;
    }
}

// and so on
```

You can add a line in your `composer.json` file to autoload it.

```json
    ...
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "app/helper.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    ...
```

You might need to run composer update after this though.