# Laravel - require php script in a service provider

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, laravel-5.5

I am quite new to Laravel and implemented the service provider for my helper functions using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32422699/4171578) on SO.

It recommended to:

> in the **register** function of your newly generated
>   HelperServiceProvider.php add following code
>
> ```
> require_once app_path('Helpers/AnythingHelper.php');
> ```

However, [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/providers#writing-service-providers) state that register method should only be used to bind things into the container:

> As mentioned previously, within the register method, you should only
>   bind things into the service container. You should never attempt to
>   register any event listeners, routes, or any other piece of
>   functionality within the register method.

In my case the app works as it is, with require a statement in the register function, so my question is more about 'best practices' rather than making the code work.

Question:

Is this a good/acceptable approach (require statement in a register method), or should I rather move require statement to the boot method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recommended approach if you put here only methods (not classes):

1. Create file anywhere you want
2. In `composer.json` make sure you add this file to `files` key inside `autoload` like this:

   ```
   "autoload": {
       // here other autoload things

       "files": ["app/Helpers/AnythingHelper.php"]
   },
   ```
3. Run `composer`dump-autoload`

For classes obviously you should use standard PSR-4 autoloading

Comment: so you'd say to ditch the service provider approach altogether for things like helper functions and handle it through composer, right?

Comment: If you have file with simple functions I don't see any point to use service provider, you can use composer to autoload those files. The same thing is done in Laravel for helper files. Just look at https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/composer.json and you will see `src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php"` loaded in this way

Comment: makes sense, I'll handle it through composer then :) but theoretically assuming I'd want to keep it in the service provides, should the require statement be moved to the boot method? I just want to make sure that I understand the docs correctly on this end - is doing anything other than binding things (i.e. using bind, singleton, instance etc. methods of app) to the container a big 'no no' in the register method? Should anything else be moved to the boot method by default?