# How to pass a custom function to a Laravel Blade template?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have a custom function and I want to pass it in a blade template. Here is the function:

```
function trim_characters( $text, $length = 45, $append = '&hellip;' ) {

    $length = (int) $length;
    $text = trim( strip_tags( $text ) );

    if ( strlen( $text ) > $length ) {
        $text = substr( $text, 0, $length + 1 );
        $words = preg_split( "/[\s]|&nbsp;/", $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY );
        preg_match( "/[\s]|&nbsp;/", $text, $lastchar, 0, $length );
        if ( empty( $lastchar ) )
            array_pop( $words );

        $text = implode( ' ', $words ) . $append;
    }

    return $text;
}
```

And the usage is like this:

```
$string = "A VERY VERY LONG TEXT";
trim_characters( $string );
```

Is it possible to pass a custom function to the blade template? Thank you.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You don't have to *pass* anything to blade. If you define your function, you can use it from blade.

---

1. Create a new `app/helpers.php` file.
2. Add your `trim_characters` function to it.
3. [Add that file to your `composer.json` file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28290332/best-practices-for-custom-helpers-on-laravel-5/28290359#28290359).
4. Run `composer dump-autoload`.

---

Now just use the function directly in blade:

```
{{ trim_characters($string) }}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me.  I get `Call to undefined function` and the function is printed in plain text at the top of the page!?

Comment: Works perfect for me.  Thanks.

Comment: @Joseph Silber  is there a way to run 'composer dump-autoload' command on hosting using web.php using laravel 5.3

Answer (score 4):

Another approach is injecting service. See docs at https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/blade#service-injection

Define your function inside a class then inject it inside your Blade

```php
class Foo {
    trim_characters($string) {....}
}
```

Then in your blade file

```php
@inject('foo', 'Foo')

<div>{{ $foo->trim_characters($string) }}</div>
```