# Pass variable from custom Laravel Helpers to Blade file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to create a helper to centralize a complicated Form::select.

My helper:

```
namespace App\Helpers;
use Log;
use App\Countries;

class Address {
    public static function country() {
        $countries = Countries::orderby('name_zh','asc');
        $form = "Form::select('countries', \$countries);";
        return $form;
    }
}
```

My View:

```
{!! Address::country() !!}
```

I would like to have this select form with `$countries` variable from this helper and show a Dropdown list on my view. How do I do it?

Comment: Have you registered your helper class to `composer.json` file? And then you can use like: `{{ country($your_blade_file_variable) }}` Let me know if this works!

Comment: Yes to I did register my helper class and it works.

Comment: My question is to use `$countries` from this helper in my view. Is this possible?

Comment: You want countries or the select html code ??

Comment: I want my view to display a form select with array `$countries`. This `$countries` array is generate inside this helper. Is this possible?

Comment: You were `return $form;` in your helper, so that you can access it like: `{{ country($your_blade_file_variable) }}`  in your blade file!

Comment: Or variables can be only compacted/passing from controller?

Comment: You can get idea from this question's answer!: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32430255/pass-a-custom-function-to-laravel-blade-template

Comment: Thank Gobel, but I would like to pass variable from my helper. For the question's answer you sent me, it's having a variable `$string` from somewhere. I would like a helper having its own array and to show a form select on my view. Is this possible?

Comment: Try below answer, is that works for you which is edited?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your helper create the select using the Laravel Collective helper the return it t the view, do it like this:

```
public static function country() {
    $countries = Countries::orderby('name_zh','asc')
                            ->pluck('name', 'id');
    return Form::select('countries', $countries);
}
```

In the view just call the method :

```
{{ Address::country() }}
```

---

Or if you want the `$countries` variable as well you can send it to the view from the controller then send it to the helper as well :

```
public function controllerFunction() {
    $countries = Countries::orderby('name_zh','asc')
                            ->get();
    return view('yourView')->withCountries($countries);
}
```

And in the view you have access to this `$countries` then pass it to the helper :

```
{{ Address::country($countries->pluck('name', 'id')) }}
```

And the helper this time should look like this :

```
public static function country($countries) {
    return Form::select('countries', $countries);
}
```

Comment: Thank Maraboc but no luck. This is what I get: `exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Invalid argument supplied for foreach()' in C:\wamp64\www\Fundmall\vendor\laravelcollective\html\src\FormBuilder.php:543 Stack trace: #0 ` What does this mean for?

Comment: Can you show me the output of `dd($countries);` in the helper before the return statment ?

Comment: I used dd($countries) and found it's my mistake. Your solution is now working, thanks Maraboc!

Comment: Happy to help ;)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to really understand your question...

But if you want to pass your `$countries` variable to your view, your function have to simply return this variable.

```
public static function country()
{
    $countries = ...;
    return $countries;
}
```

Then, two choices :

- Use your function into your controller

  ```
  use App\Helpers\Address;
  // code code code
  public function controllerFunc()
  {
      // code
      $countries = Address::country();

      return view('yourview', compact($countries));
  }
  ```

  And get it in your view :

  ```
  <!-- Dump your $countries (from controller) var -->
  {{ dd($countries) }}
  ```
- Use your function into your view

  ```
  <!-- Dump your $countries (from helper) var -->
  {{ dd(\App\Helpers\Address::country()) }}
  ```

Now, if you want to pass directly your select, then in your static function, return `Form::select('countries', $countries')` like Maraboc said.