# Laravel 5: Global Auth $user variable in all controllers

Tags: php, laravel, global-variables

In my BaseController I have this:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    View::share('user', $user);
}
```

I can access the $user array throughout all of my views but what if I want it to be a global variable available in all of my Controllers?

I have the following working code:

```
use Auth;
use DB;

class UsersController extends BaseController
{
   public function index()
   {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $users = DB::table('users')->where('user_id', $user->user_id)->get();
        return view('pages.users.index', compact('users');
    }
}
```

I want the $user variable available in all of my controllers and within all of the public functions within each on the controllers but I don't want to have to redeclare "use Auth;" and "$user = Auth::user();"

I tried adding it to a __construct in the BaseController but that didn't seem to work, Undefined $user variable error. Any thoughts? I know it's possible.

Comment: Look at laravel middleware this might help you. http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/middleware

Comment: Why don't you use a helper function for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Has shown in other answers, you can:

- set it as a property of your base controller (I don't recommend this, it just adds clutter)
- create a custom helper (see below)
- just do `\Auth::user()`

Another technique, you can use `auth()` helper:

```
auth()->user()
```

It is even [documented](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-auth).

According to [this PR](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/8818), there is no plan to add an `user()` helper in Laravel.

If you consider it is worth adding this helper to your project, here is the code:

```
function user()
{
    // short and sweet
    return auth()->user();

    // alternative, saves one function call!!
    return app('Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard')->user();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I do not see why something like this would not work:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->user = \Auth::user();
    \View::share('user', $this->user);
}
```

This way it's available to all your views and as long as your controllers are extending `BaseController`, it's available in all your controllers as well with `$this->user`.

Comment: At the time that Controller's constructor is called the session is not initialized yet, so `Auth::user() == null`.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use a helper function. It won't give you a $user variable, but it can give you a more cleaner way to accomplish this.

In your **helpers.php** add a function:

```
function getUser(){
    return Auth::user();
}
```

In all other places (controller, views, models) call: `getUser()`. That's it.

If you don't have any helper file for your functions yet. You can follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28290359/2169355) to create one.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see whats the issue with using `Auth::user()`, this class is using singleton pattern which means that if the `Auth::user()` is already initialized it won't check again against the database especially when most of the code shouldn't even be inside a controller so basically you would still need to do `Auth::user()` inside your services, models, form requests, etc..

```
abstract class Controller extends BaseController {
    protected $user;
    use ValidatesRequests;
    public  function ___construct(){
        $this->user = \Auth::user();
    } 
}
```