# Laravel, how to get a warning if a language phrase doesn't exists?

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel localization builtin to translate phrases.

In my view I have `{{ trans('site.phrase') }}`. Let's say I mispell the keyword and type:

```
{{ trans('site.prase') }} //without h
```

Now in my view I will have a: `site.prase`. Is there any way to obtain a warning from Laravel in the log ?

### Edit

Following comments and the answer I am now using a simple custom helper:

```
// trans_safe
function transs( $key, $params = []) {
    $localized = trans($key, $params);
    if ($localized == $key) {
        \Log::warning("Key: {$key} doesn't exists with language: " . \App::getLocale() . ", url: " . \Request::fullUrl());
    }
    return $localized;
}
```

Now in the view I use: `{{ transs('site.key) }}`

Comment: Since `trans()` will return the string provided if there's no available translation, you could simply check `if(trans($phrase) == $phrase)`, but this would require your knowing/defining the phrase beforehand. Just a thought.

Comment: @TimLewis: i am using basically that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel's helper doesn't support this. You'll have to create your own helper for that:

```php
function translate($id = null, $parameters = [], $domain = 'messages', $locale = null)
{
    $translator = app('translator');

    if (is_null($id)) {
        return app('translator');
    }

    if (! $translator->has($id, $locale)) {
        throw new \Exception('Translate key does not exist');
    }

    return app('translator')->trans($id, $parameters, $domain, $locale);
}
```

Where should I put this helper function? [Glad you asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28290332/best-practices-for-custom-helpers-on-laravel-5#28290359).

Comment: interesting! I did something like that. Anyway what is $domain param for ?

Comment: Don't worry about it. [The `trans` function doesn't even utilize it](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/aec203a2168a8286bf1fdaf1e90c0d19619b79ea/src/Illuminate/Translation/Translator.php#L182-L185). Probably there for legacy reasons.

Comment: i found a bug, $translator->has doesn't work if the fallback_locale returns a localized value