# php artisan clear-compiled failing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, laravel-artisan

I cloned an existing `laravel5` project from github repository. In my root using Mac terminal I ran `composer install` I got out put of dependency installation and at some point when output reached

`> php artisan clear-compiled`

I got the following error

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare createDirIfNotExist() (previously
>   declared in
>   /Users/applebook/projects/referral-system/Laravel5/laravel/config/constants.php:14)
>   in
>   /Users/applebook/projects/referral-system/Laravel5/laravel/config/constants.php
>   on line 20

`Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the pre-update-cmd event returned with an error`

I'm stuck here since past few hours, nothing is working out. any command `artisan` , `php artisan --version` `composer update` is giving me same error.

Can anyone help me get through this ? Also if anybody suggest me a good tutorial setting up existing laravel5 project on `mac os x` ?

File under `config/constants.php` have the following code:

`//Ariel
//define('FILE_PATH', "/Users/ariel_inter/git");
//define('INVOICES_PATH', FILE_PATH . "/invoices");
//define('PROFILE_PATH', FILE_PATH . "/profiles");`

`//Server
define('FILE_PATH', "/var/www/files");
define('INVOICES_PATH', FILE_PATH . "/invoices");
define('PROFILE_PATH', FILE_PATH . "/profiles");`

`function createDirIfNotExist($pathDir, $octalPermissions) {
    $result = TRUE;
    if (!file_exists($pathDir)) {
        $result = mkdir($pathDir, $octalPermissions, TRUE);
    }
    return $result;
}`

`function getContentTypeByExtensionFile($ext) {
    $result = "";`

```
if($ext === 'pdf') {
    return "application/pdf";
} else if($ext === 'png') {
    return "image/png";
} else if($ext === 'jpg') {
    return "image/jpeg";
} else if($ext === 'jpeg') {
    return "image/jpeg";
}

return $result;
```

}`

Comment: Tried `compose dump-autoload` and then composer install?

Comment: yes @BharatGeleda i ran `composer dump-autoload` and then `composer install` but it's the same issue....

Comment: Which project are you trying to clone? Add a link.

Comment: it's in private repository, working on a client's project

Comment: can you show us constants.php line 14 and constants.php line 20 ?

Comment: I've edited my question and added function present in `config/constants.php`

Comment: you gave 6 line of code, but the error is on line 14 and 20

Comment: yup it's exactly the same function, function starting at line 14 and ending at line 20, edited my question again and added complete code in that file

Answer (score 0):

From your error ， i can suggest, the function **createDirIfNotExist** has been loaded more then once, here is some suggestions to fix it:

1. global search function createDirIfNotExist from all you project, if you find other files contains this function , only keep one in your project,
2. if above didn't solve you problem, you need to debug where this file (which have function createDirIfNotExist) been include, then try fix it to include_once/require_once.
3. cut function createDirIfNotExist to a helper function,[laravel create helper function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28290332/best-practices-for-custom-helpers-on-laravel-5)