# Laravel5, where to put this generic code

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I have some php lines which will be used very often in my application. So I would like to build a function and call it every where in my app. My function could be :

```
static function array_matiere($id_ecole) {
     return $something;
}
```

I tried to put this code in a controller and then call it like that :

```
$liste_matieres = MatieresController::array_matieres(Session::get('id_ecole'));
```

It works, but where to put this kind of function ? in the controller ? in a method file ? what is the best practice ?

Thanks for your responses.

Dominique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to implement this. look here

**Method 1** This method is highly suggested by Laravel Expert ( JeffreyWay)

If your helper functions are similar to the way laravel 5 ones work, i.e `Illuminate/Support/helpers.php` you could just create a `helpers.php` and have composer do the autoloading for you.

Edit your `composer.json` file and add the file to the autoloading key. In my example my app is called Tasky so just add the files key and reference `helpers.php`.

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "Tasky\\": "app/"
    },
    "files": [
        "app/Support/helpers.php"
    ]
},
```

That way you just create your file inside `app/Support/helpers.php` and all your common function based view helpers or other helpers can go here. If you take the class based approach then the above is great.

Also then remember to just run the following once.

> $ composer dumpautoload

[Source](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/best-practices-for-custom-helpers-on-laravel-5?page=1#reply-28978)

**Method 2**

[Please Follow the link and read answer & Its comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28290332/best-practices-for-custom-helpers-on-laravel-5/28360186#28360186)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever u need to include a piece of code providing some functionality through out your  application then the best way in Laravel is to make Service class inside app/Services and then you can use that class anywhere in your application using

```
   use App\Services\YourServiceName;
```