# What is the best practice to use helpers in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Hello I am creating a big Laravel application.

I want to create a punch of helper functions (may be 1000 functions) to be used in templates and modules within the application.

What is the best practice to do these helpers?

1. Using **helpers class** and put functions inside class
2. Using **functions** and autoload helper files

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best practices for custom helpers on Laravel 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28290332/best-practices-for-custom-helpers-on-laravel-5)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can go any of these ways, but probably you'd want to create `helpers.php` file with all your helper functions and then autoload this file as Laravel creators did it with `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\helpers.php`

Good practice is to use your own class, of course. But still, since you're using Laravel you might want to use same approach as Laravel creators use.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I know how to do both ways, but I am asking what is the best practice and is one of these ways slower or may cause issues if I used in large scale?

Comment: Good practice is to use your own class, of course. But still, since you're using Laravel you might want to use same approach as Laravel creators use.

Answer (score 5):

i think you have to follow this link http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/how-to-create-custom-helper-in-laravel-5example.html for create custom helper.

First create helpers.php file in following path : app/Http/helpers.php and

Open your composer.json file and add this:

```
    "files": [
    "app/Http/helpers.php"
]
```

then

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Now you can use helper function any where.