# Making a value from db accessible system wide in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to know the best way to go about displaying a value from the database system wide in Laravel 5?

Basically, all authenticated users should have it set and I want to use it in a couple of places.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing too much about your setup/needs, I'd say you should [create your own helpers file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28290332/best-practices-for-custom-helpers-on-laravel-5/28290359#28290359) and put a simple function in there:

```php
function special_value()
{
    static $value;

    if (is_null($value)) {
        $value = DB::table('the_table')->value('the_column');
    }

    return $value;
}
```

Then, wherever you need the value, just call `special_value()` to get it.