# share method between controllers Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In several controllers i have to use the same method to show results as table with column sorting functionality:

```
 public function showSearchResults(Request $req){

        $query=Service::where('title', $req->search);

        // Columns sorting 
        if ($req->has('order')){
            $order= $req->order=='asc' ? 'asc' : 'desc';
            $order_inverse=$req->order=='asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc';
        } else {
            $order='desc';
            $order_inverse='asc';
        }

         ...


        $url=$req->url().'?'.http_build_query($req->except('sortby','order','page'));
        $results=$query->with('type')->paginate(15)->appends($req->all());


        return View::make('services.search_results')
                    ->with('results', $results)
                    ->with('url',$url)
                    ->with('sortby', $sortby)
                    ->with('order', $order)
                    ->with('order_inverse', $order_inverse);

    }
```

What is the best approach to avoid DRY in such case?

Comment: _“In several controllers i have to use the same method to show results as table with column sorting functionality. What is the best approach to avoid DRY in such case?”_ I’d first ask *why* you have controllers that are doing the same thing? Instead of skirting around the issue with a solution like traits, look at the *real* problem here: you have multiple controllers doing the same thing.

Comment: Traits, as others have suggested, are the best way to do this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Sharing methods among Controllers with Traits

**Step 1:** Create a Trait

```
<?php // Code in app/Traits/MyTrait.php

namespace App\Traits;

trait MyTrait
{
    protected function showSearchResults(Request $request)
    {
        // Stuff
    }
}
```

**Step 2:** `use` the Trait in your Controller:

```
<?php // Code in app/Http/Controllers/MyController.php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Traits\MyTrait; // <-- you'll need this line...

class MyController extends Controller
{
    use MyTrait; // <-- ...and also this line.

    public function getIndex(Request $request)
    {
        // Now you can call your function with $this context
        $this->showSearchResults($request);
    }
}
```

Now you can `use` your Trait in any other controller in the same manner.

It is important to note that you don't need to `include` or `require` your Trait file anywhere, [PSR-4 Autoloading](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) takes care of file inclusion.

You can also use Custom Helper classes as others have mentioned but I would recommend against it if you only intend to share code among controllers.  [You can see how to create custom helper classes here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28290332/best-practices-for-custom-helpers-on-laravel-5#32772686).

Answer (score 2):

You can use traits (as ventaquil suggested) or you can create custom [helpers](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/50/creating-a-helpers-file) file and add helpers there.

After that, you'll be able to use this helper from any class (controllers, models, custom classes, commands etc) like any other [Laravel helper](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#available-methods).

Answer (score 0):

Use traits? More available here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php

Answer (score 0):

You can create a helper file in your app directory. for eg. MethodHelper.php

In this file you can mention the method that you require using anywhere.
For instance,

```
<?php namespace App;
class MethodHelper
{
 public static function reusableMethod()
    {
        //logic
    }
}
```

You can use this method anywhere, by using the namespace and calling the method.
In the above eg.
The namespace would be:

The method call function would look like:

```
MethodHelper::reusableMethod();
```

You can send parameters too based on your functional requirements.
In your eg. you could have

```
public function showSearchResults(Request $req){
//
}
```

instead of reusableMethod().
Your call would be:

```
MethodHelper::showSearchResults($req);
```