# Laravel - specify a default/fallback string for multi-language

Tags: php, laravel-4, translation, multilingual

I am starting to add multi-language to a site that uses Laravel for frontend.

However, due to lack of resources at the moment, I am translating the strings as I go. It will be a while before whole site is translated.

The only challenge is that if a text is not translated what get displayed is the key. I would like to specify a default/fallback string for such.

e.g.

```
{{ trans('site.'.$name) }}
```

If I pass 'Business' as $name and there' no translation for 'Business' in site.php lang file I end up with `site.Business` on the frontend. This messes up everything. In the worst case, if there's no `site.Business`, Laravel should output `Business`.

Even better it should provide an option for default/fallback string.

Is this possible?

On a side note is there a free translation for common words? This will save time having to translate everything myself.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fallback language is what you should be using. See the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/localization)

> You may also configure a "fallback language", which will be used when
>   the active language does not contain a given language line. Like the
>   default language, the fallback language is also configured in the
>   `app/config/app.php` configuration file:

`'fallback_locale' => 'en',`

It will surely take you just as much time writing in a fallback inline as it would simply writing in the fallback in a parallel translation file as you write in the translation key. The time spent thinking of an alternate way versus just doing it is going to be negligible in the end.

If you really want an inline fallback, then you need to create a new helper method that does something different. So prepare yourself for some home brewed awesomeness.

Let's create a new function that we can use in any view. I will use the method described by [Joseph Sibler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28290359/1090438). Create a file called `helpers.php` inside `app`. Then add this to your `composer.json` in the `autoload` object under a `files` array as `"app/helpers.php"`. Not sure what I mean? See his answer. After adding, run `composer dump-autoload`.

Now, let's add a `trans_fb()` method that will take all the parameters of the `trans()` method, but with a fallback as well. I will define this method such that the first two arguments are required, (the key, and the fallback).

If Laravel cannot find the translation key (it searches in `resources/lang/en/auth.php` for example `auth.failed` as a key) it will use the fallback instead, and pass any other optional arguments for the original method.

```
<?php

if (! function_exists('trans_fb')) {
    /**
     * Translate the given message with a fallback string if none exists.
     *
     * @param  string  $id
     * @param  string  $fallback
     * @param  array   $parameters
     * @param  string  $domain
     * @param  string  $locale
     * @return \Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface|string
     */
    function trans_fb($id, $fallback, $parameters = [], $domain = 'messages', $locale = null)
    {
        return ($id === ($translation = trans($id, $parameters, $domain, $locale))) ? $fallback : $translation;
    }
}
```

You can then use this in a template like so:

`{{ trans_fb("i.love.laravel", "I love Laravel!") }}`

Comment: I had already ready about the fallback language but didn't look viable in my situation. I will try out using an alternative helper function as suggested. Thanks.

Comment: If it wasn't viable then this should be all you need :) Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this solution which uses the same parameters as `trans()` method and when key is not translated, it returns the translated string using the application `'fallback_locale'` from `app.php`.

I still wonder why it's not implemented natively in Laravel and Laravel just returnes untranslated key.

```php
if (!function_exists('trans_fb')) {
    function trans_fb(string $key, array $replace = [], ?string $locale = null)
    {
        $translation = trans($key, $replace, $locale);

        if ($key === $translation) {
            return trans($key, $replace, config('app.fallback_locale'));
        }

        return $translation;
    }
}
```

Comment: Laravel already tries to use the translation from the `fallback_locale` if the key does not match the target language and only matches the fallback language. I suspect something else is going on on your system.