# Cannot declare class Controller, because the name is already in use

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I recently migrated a laravel 4.2 project to 5.0. So far I have completed all the necessary steps but I keep getting an error.

> Cannot declare class Controller, because the name is already in use

My Controller is changed as provided by laravel in the upgrade guide.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesCommands;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;

abstract class Controller extends BaseController {

    use DispatchesCommands, ValidatesRequests;

}
```

Also I have added it to the classmap directive of my composer.json.

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database",
        "app/Http/Controllers"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
```

I couldn't find any solution so far so if you guys know what to do it would help me out a lot :) thanks in advance!

Comment: Note the missing namespace

Comment: sometimes this error happens in spite of there is a namespace but the path of the namespace is incorrect!
In my case, I put my controller in a subfolder and forgot to correct/update its new namespace!

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Sub_Dir\Name_Of_Controller.php

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Remove the `"app/Http/Controllers"` from your classmap.

Add `namespace App\Http\Controllers;` above your `use` blocks.

Then run `composer dump-auto`

Comment: This makes me have to write the whole path of a controller in my routes.php is that normal behaviour?

Comment: In your `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php` include `routes.php` and define the namespace in the route group like:

Comment: `$router->group(['namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers'], function ($router) {
            require app_path('Http/routes.php');
        });`

Comment: protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers'; did the trick in RouteServiceProvider

Comment: Yup!  Another cool thing to add with this is if you add more route groups you can use another namespace for all those controllers or extend that namespace if it is in that routes file.  So you can do `['namespace' => 'Api']` which will reference your controllers in the `App\Http\Controllers\Api` namesapce

Comment: This error occurs when we provide the wrong namespace path.

Answer (score 15):

In case if you have your controller inside a folder instead of app/Http/Controller you should declare that namespace like this:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\folderName;
```

Note:

Probably you are extending base `Controller` so you should add this also:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
```

Otherwise this error occurs:

```
 Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Controller' not found
```

Answer (score 10):

I'm pretty sure you have to add namespaces.

> Namespacing
>
> By default, Laravel 4 applications did not utilize namespacing within your application code. So, for example, all Eloquent models and controllers simply lived in the "global" namespace. For a quicker migration, you can simply leave these classes in the global namespace in Laravel 5 as well.

Comment: commonly a namespace issue, so ensure you define the namespace at the top of the file

Comment: it's because you have user model inside a folder not directly on /App....

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem with you, and this is my solution to fix it maybe it can help you.
Add namespace App\Http\Controllers; under <?php

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

When Creating Auto Discovery Events and their Listener classes, Just add below namespace at the top of your Listener class to avoid this error:

```
namespace App\Listeners;
```

Answer (score 0):

---

If you are using Laravel 8 or above, you can use Anonymous Migration to avoid the conflict with Class name.

Below is how you to declare an Anonymous Migration. Do not forget the semicolon at the end.

---

```
return new class extends Migration{
    //
};
```