# How to Use Function inside @foreach - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, foreach, laravel-blade

Thanks For Reading.
I'm new in Laravel, i want to try to change the output of Database with @foreach blade, there is the example :

This is Route :

```
Route::get('/home', 'warnajati@index');
```

This is Controller :

```
public function index()
{
    $post = DB::table('posts')->get();
    return view('warnajati', ['posts'=>$post]);
}
```

This is Views :

```
 @foreach ($posts as $post)
   <div class="title"><h3>{{$post->title}}</h3></div>
 @endforeach
```

with Output of `$post->title` is `"This is The Looonger Title you ever know"` ,
and i want to make the title is shorter with `Wordlimit()` function i have made :

```
function wordlimit($text, $limit=10)
{
    if (strlen($text)>$limit) {
        # code...
        $word = mb_substr($text,0,$limit-3)."...";
    }else{
        $word =$text;
    }
};
```

How and Where i must place that function in laravel Project ?? please help me..

Comment: Your function has no return value... Laravel already has this function: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-str-limit

Comment: Where is your wordlimit function? You might be able to use the function as you normally would, depending on the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function has no return value... Laravel already has this function: http://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-str-limit

```
 @foreach ($posts as $post)
   <div class="title"><h3>{{ str_limit($post->title, 10) }}</h3></div>
 @endforeach
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Laravel's Accessor`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) for doing that like this inside a Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    public function getShortTitleAttribute($value)
    {
        // return shortened title here ...
    }
}
```

and then you can use it in blade like this:

```
{{ $post->short_title }}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You really should try to avoid putting view (formatting) related logic inside your model, otherwise you'll end up with some very bulky models.

Comment: I know but its also not the bad way, as if we don't find the logic like `str_limit` we can do using this too..Its just the Laravel Way for solving complex things and make the code readable and cean

Comment: The Laravel way involves separation of concerns.  This would be violated if mutators are being used for display formatting.  In my mind, setting a string limit like this only makes sense in the context of the view.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your function in **helpers.php** file from libraries folder.
Just make sure that you have helpers.php file autoloaded in composer.json file:

```
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "libraries/helpers.php"
    ],
},
```

If you had to add this to your composer.json you will also have to run `composer dump-autoload` command from terminal.

For more info check out [Best practices for custom helpers on Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28290332/best-practices-for-custom-helpers-on-laravel-5/).