# Laravel yield attribute

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-views

I'm trying to set an attribute using **@yield** and **@section**, but how?
I tried to use

```
<html @yield('mainApp')>
```

and

```
@section('mainApp','id="myid"')
```

but it returns **id=&quot;myid&quot;** instead of **id="myid"**

I know that I can manage it with a default *id* but I don't like this way, and also what if I need to use a custom attribute?

Comment: Perfect!! work in my project and based on larvel 5.3. but if used Laravel 5.4, inline content passed to a section is automatically escaped then used
 @section('mainApp', {!! 'id="myid"' !!})

Answer (score 16):

Laravel escapes HTML by default. I therefore see that you have two choices.

1. Expose the value to the view as a variable in your controller.

   `view()->share('mainApp', sprintf('id="%s"', 'myid'));`

Then output the value unescaped.

```
<html {!! $mainApp !!}
```

2. Only yield the `id` attribute value, not the entire attribute.

   `@section('mainApp')
       myid
   @stop`

   `<html id="@yield('mainApp', '')">`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as I said, I already know the things you posted. Anyway, I'll vote up for the controller solution.

Comment: No worries. I used the controller solution when using Laravel to render pages with embedded Angular apps. And sorry, I didn't realise that you meant default `id` being an empty value.

Comment: Option #2  FTW! !

Answer (score 9):

On your controller you do something like:

```
return view('my_page')->with('myid', 'myid');
```

and on your view/layout you do something like:

```
<html {{ $myid or '' }}>
...
```

You don't need to yield for such a task.

Answer (score 8):

If you check the Upgrade Guide from the link below you will see few lines below under Blade:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/upgrade

```
    @section Escaping
```

In Laravel 5.4, inline content passed to a section is automatically escaped:

```
    @section('title', $content)
```

If you would like to render unescaped content in a section, you must declare the section using the traditional "long form" style:

```
    @section('title')
        {!! $content !!}
    @stop
```

**So the get the result for for your query you need to as below:**

```
    @section('mainApp', {!! 'id="myid"' !!})
```

Answer (score 5):

Which Laravel version you are used? In the Laravel 5.4, there's an update about this:

> Blade
>
> @section Escaping
>
> In Laravel 5.4, inline content passed to a section is automatically
>   escaped:
>
> @section('title', $content)
>
> If you would like to render unescaped
>   content in a section, you must declare the section using the
>   traditional "long form" style:
>
> @section('title')
>       {!! $content !!} 
>   @stop

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/upgrade

Long short story, try to use **Laravel 5.4** and then use this code

```
@section('mainApp')
    id="myid"
@stop
```

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you use like this:

```
@section('mainApp') id='myid' @endsection
```

This will not escaping the character.

Answer (score 3):

So a better way to do this if i understand you, is using @stack and @push

```
<html class="no-js" lang="en" @stack('mainApp')>
```

And what ever page you want to send the id use @push

```
@push('mainApp')
 id='myid'
@endpush
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade#stacks

can even add variables or what every you like in there and it will go where the @stack is

Comment: Shows single quotes in html.

Comment: i put single quotes by mistake  change it to id="myid"

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this would help:

```
{!! $__env->yieldContent('mainApp') !!}
```

That said, using laravel 5.4, your way works fine for me.. which version are you using?

Answer (score 2):

if used Laravel 5.4, inline content passed to a section is automatically escaped.

then remove automatically escaped in section for used

```
@section('mainApp', {!! 'id="myid"' !!})
```

Answer (score 2):

The section default content is escaped using the `e()` helper. Since Laravel 5.1 you can use `Illuminate\Support\HtmlString`, this class *html* content it's *not escaped* but *directly rendered* by the Laravel `e()` helper function, i.e.:

```
@section('mainApp', new Illuminate\Support\HtmlString('id="myid"'))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achieve `<html id="myid">` you can do that this way :

in your html tag add this:

```
<html @yield('mainApp')>
```

and in your template :

```
@section('mainApp', "id=myid") // this will give you <html id="myid">
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested it in a laravel 5.4 and what is working for me is:

This is in my layout

```
<html lang="en" @yield('mainApp')>
```

And this in my extending view ( removed quotes wrapping myid )

```
@section('mainApp','id=myid')
```

The result is in the attached image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do this in Laravel 5.4:

HTML template (template.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html id="{{ $html_id or '' }}" lang="{{ $html_locale or 'en' }}">
    <head>
        ...

        @yield('head')

        ...
    </head>

    <body>
        ...

        @yield('body')

        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

A base template (template.main)

```
@component('template.html')
    @section('head')

       ...

    @stop


    @section('body')
        ...

        @yield('contents')

        ...
    @stop
@endcomponent
```

A page template wich will define the HTML #ID

```
@extends('template.main')


@slot('html_id')
    app-html-id
@endslot


@section('contents')
  ... 
@stop
```

Comment: Ok, but as I said, I need something to change attribute name, not just the value.

Answer (score 0):

Define your master layout with @yield

```
<html lang="{{ config('app.locale') }}" @yield('hello')>
```

Extend that master

```
@extends('layouts.app')
```

Start section hello

```
@section('hello') 
   id="myId"
@endsection
```

Output of following is like this here id="myId" is dynamic part.

```
<html id="myId" lang="en">
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you are assigning the value of `myId` but if it is just a PHP variable, have you tried passing it to your partials like this?

```
@yield('mainApp', [
    'id' => $myid
])

@section('mainApp', [
    'id' => $myid
])
```

You should be able to pass any variables from one template to another and map them to distinct variable names using a associative array of key => value pairs

Answer (score 0):

There is a `HtmlString` class you can use for this kind of things, Laravel uses it for things like `csrf_field()` and `method_field()`.

You could inline it if you'd like:

```
@section('mainApp', new \Illuminate\Support\HtmlString('id="myid"'))
```

However, I would personally create a custom helper for this so I can access it a lot easier, i.e.:

```
@section('mainApp', html_string('id="myid"'))
```

The helper should look something like..

```
function html_string($string) {
    return new \Illuminate\Support\HtmlString($string);
}
```

If you need help creating a custom helper, check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/28290359/7844646

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but maybe you could do something like this :

```
<html {!! View::getSections()['mainApp'] !!}>
```

If I am right, `View::getSections()` returns all the defined sections.

However, I don't know if it will work because maybe getSections will be called before the section is defined. But it's still worth a shot.

Answer (score -1):

Let me tell you in one line.

Start Section Name should be yield('Section Name')