# Custom helper classes in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, laravel-5.4

I have some helper classes in `app/Helpers`. How do I load these classes using a `service provider` to use them in blade templates?

e.g. If I have a class `CustomHelper` that contains a method `fooBar()` :

```
<?php

nampespace App\Helpers;

class CustomHelper
{
    static function fooBar()
    {
        return 'it works!';
    }
}
```

I want to be able to do something like this in my blade templates:

```
{{ fooBar() }}
```

instead of doing this:

```
{{ \App\Helpers\CustomHelper::fooBar() }}
```

**P.S:** @andrew-brown's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28360186/5689855) in [Best practices for custom helpers on Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28290332/best-practices-for-custom-helpers-on-laravel-5) deals with non-class files. It would be nice to have a class based solution so that the helper functions can be organized among classes.

Comment: https://laravel.io/forum/02-03-2015-best-practices-for-custom-helpers-on-laravel-5?page=1#reply-20564

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/a/32772686/2359679

Comment: You want to implement a class based solution but use it like a global function? Don't think that's possible in any language, let alone PHP or laravel

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to use only function when you have code in your classes. Well, you could try with extending Blade but it's too much.

What you should do is creating one extra file, for example `app\Helpers\helpers.php` and in your composer.json file put:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "files": ["app/Helpers/helpers.php"] // <- this line was added
},
```

create `app/Helpers/helpers.php` file and run

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Now in your `app/Helpers/helpers.php` file you could add those custom functions for example like this:

```
if (! function_exists('fooBar')) {
   function fooBar() 
   {
      return \App\Helpers\CustomHelper::fooBar();
   }
}
```

so you define global functions but in fact all of them might use specific public methods from some classes.

By the way this is exactly what Laravel does for its own helpers for example:

```
if (! function_exists('array_add')) {
    function array_add($array, $key, $value)
    {
        return Arr::add($array, $key, $value);
    }
}
```

as you see `array_add` is only shorter (or maybe less verbose) way of writing `Arr::add`