# How to access a function in every controller laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I can access a function in every view like this.

In my AppServiceProvide Code

```
public function boot()
{
    $post = Post::latest()->first();
    View::share(compact('post'));
}
```

How can i access it in every controller?

What is the best way to call a function in every controller,as i need to make sure latest record from database.

Comment: Define the function in  Controller.php use function in other controller as `$this->function()`

Comment: You can also create a static class / singleton that you can use everywhere

Comment: Yes i can do this.Is there any way like how we can call a function like we call it in view instead of $this->function() ?

Comment: I think you should create service for this

Comment: custom helper will solve your problem
[check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43168719/custom-helper-classes-in-laravel-5-4)

Answer (score 1):

```
**You can write in model also using model object**

public function YourFunction(){
  return "data";
}

**call it in your controller like this make model object suppose your 
model name is YourModel in controller you can call like this**

$model = new YourModel();
$data = $model->YourFunction(); //calling method in controller
```