# How to call custom helper in laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel

I wanna make my very own helper, and i put it in `app/http/helpers.php`. 
This is my helper code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Helpers;
use Auth;
class helper {

    public static function is_login() {
        if(Auth::check()){
           return True;
        }else{
           return False;
        }
    }

    public static function must_login(){
        if(Auth::check()){
           return True;
        }else{
           return Redirect::to('logout');;
        }
    }
}

?>
```

and this is my app.php code:

```
  'aliases' => [
                'customhelper'=> App\Helpers\Helper::class
               ]
```

when i use for my blade file `customhelper::is_login()` it work. But when i try to use in my controller `customhelper::must_login()` it doesn't work and i've got some error

> Class 'App\Http\Controllers\customhelper' not found

Comment: Did you use ```use``` statement in your controller?

Comment: have you treid `composer dump-autoload`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use your alias with the same name of Helper Class and add use statement to Controller file.

For Example :

`app/Helpers/Helper.php`

```
<?php
namespace App\Helpers;

class Helper{
    public static function SayHello()
    {
        return "SayHello";
    }
}
```

`config/app.php`

```
'aliases' => [
    /*Defaults...*/
    'Helper' => App\Helpers\Helper::class, 
],
```

`app/Http/Controllers/MyController.php`

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Helper; // Important

class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return Helper::SayHello();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Reynald Henryleo

First thing like you have mentioned `'app/http/helpers.php'` your helper file path in that case your namespace should be `'namespace App\Http'`.

for better understanding to make global helper function refer **'Custom Classes in Laravel 5, the Easy Way'** section of [Best practices for custom helpers on Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28290332/best-practices-for-custom-helpers-on-laravel-5)