# Add domain parameter to all subroutes automatically

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to make it so that I can have all routes inside of a group automatically use a domain parameter without having to specify it in views and whatnot. Here is an example of what I am looking for.

Route group code:

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{tenant_domain}.myapp.com', 'middleware' => 'tenant'], function () {
```

The `tenant` middleware handle:

```
public function handle($request, $next)
{
    session(['tenant_domain' => $request->route('tenant_domain')]);

    return $next($request);
}
```

So instead of having to use this code in all my views:

```
{{ route('login', ['tenant_domain' => session('tenant_domain')]) }}
```

I'd like to only use:

```
{{ route('login') }}
```

And then in the `boot()` method of `RouteServiceProvider`, have something like:

```
public function boot()
{
    if (isset(session('my_parameter'))) {
        Route::addParameter(['tenant_domain' => session('tenant_domain')]);
    }

    parent::boot();
}
```

How can I do this properly so it works?

Comment: I'd have the middleware do `config('tenant.domain', $request->route('tenant_domain'))` and just use `config('tenant.domain')` where you want to access the variable.

Comment: How do I make it so I don't have to include `tenant_domain` as a parameter for the routes inside the group? I've tried using `$request->route()->forgetParameter('tenant_domain')` in the `tenant` middleware and it doesn't work.

Comment: Ohhhhh, I understand the question better now. Sorry, I don't have an answer there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you automatically bind it to a route. However you can overwrite all Laravel helpers because it is checked if they exist before they are defined:

```
if (! function_exists('route')) { //etc }}
```

So you could rewrite the route function (originally located in `Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php` with something like this:

```
/**
* Generate the URL to a named route.
*
* @param  string  $name
* @param  array   $parameters
* @param  bool    $absolute
* @return string
*/
function route($name, $parameters = [], $absolute = true)
{
    if (session()->has('tenant_domain'))) {
        $parameters = array_prepend($parameters, session()->get('tenant_domain'));
    }
    return app('url')->route($name, $parameters, $absolute);
}
```

You can find how to add a custom helper in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28290332/best-practices-for-custom-helpers-on-laravel-5).

Comment: This is OK but then I still have to add `$tenant_domain` to all my controller methods...how can I avoid that?

Comment: It appears the solution is to use your helper function as well as `forgetParameter` so it doesn't need to be injected into controller methods. Thank you.

Comment: Ah very cool, didn't know about `forgetParameter`. So a middleware to do `$request->route()->forgetParameter('tenant_domain');`?