# Laravel - Generate url for an asset accessed via subdomain

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

In my Laravel site, I am serving my assets via CDN at https://cdn.example.com/asset.js. If I know the asset name, how can I generate a URL to the asset?

So far I have managed to generate https://example.com/asset.js by doing `asset(Storage::url('asset.js'));`, but I can't figure out how to add the subdomain, either by calling different methods or editing config.

Any ideas?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

put your assets in public folder within or without folder and fetch those assets like css, js or any with

```
{{ asset('myassset.js') }}
```

or if in any folder then

```
{{ asset('myfolder/asset.js') }}
```

`

Comment: That will only create https://example.com/asset.js not  https://cdn.example.com/asset.js

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating a custom function that can be called with `asset_cdn('asset.js')` might a better solution.

```
function asset_cdn( $asset, $secure = false ){
   $protocol = $secure ? 'https:' : 'http:';

   return $protocol . '//cdn.example.com/' . $asset;
}
```

How to make custom function in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28290332).