# How do i perform an operation on resulted mysql query result without looping/foreach

Tags: php, laravel, php-7, php-5.6, eloquent

```
 $users = User:all(); 
//User:all() is based on the laravel eloquent model , it's just similar to 'select * from user' query

 $total_spend_amount = 0;

     foreach($users as $user)
    {
       $total_spend_amount += $user->spend_amount;
    }

    echo "Total spend amount :".$total_spend_amount;

//Note: In this simple example i just want to sum of all the spend_amount
```

Above are just a simple example , how do i do some algorithm on the resulted query without looping/foreach in php?

```
User::all()->sum('spend_amount'); // this is the answer below and this is correct
//but how about if i want the 'specific algorithm' to be performed on the resulted query instead of sum?
```

But how about if i want the 'specific algorithm' to be performed on the resulted query instead of sum?

Comment: do you just want sum of spend_amount ?

Comment: @GauravGupta not just sum , if possible , i want the custom one.

Comment: I dunno Laravel from a bar of soap, but don't you wanna apply a `reduce` handler to your collection? https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-reduce

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure about syntax but try with

```
User::all()->sum('spend_amount');
```

or

```
User::all()->select(DB::raw("SUM(spend_amount)")->get();
```

Comment: i know laravel can do this , like i state at the question above, sum is just example , how about i want custom algorithm to be performed instead of sum?

Comment: Make another example and a more precise question. I'll try to give you another example and a more precise response.

Comment: @sensorario your respond is right , **but** how about i want the custom one instead of sum?

Comment: It depends on what you need. Really. I cannot tell you all cases you have not mentioned here. Make a more precise question.

Comment: ... maybe you can "send" the result to a service (I am talking about domain driven design). And write a family of collaborators and value object. You can resolve your problem with functional programming. You can send data to a rest api that resolves any custom issue.

Comment: So, ... why dont you mark my answer as right if it is right? XD

Answer (score 1):

Laravel provides `sum()` by default using eloquent.

```
$total_spent_amount = DB::table('users')->all()->sum('spent_amount`);
```

Comment: i know laravel can do this , like i state at the question above, sum is just example , how about i want custom algorithm to be performed instead of sum?

Comment: You may define a custom helper function in Laravel. Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28290332/best-practices-for-custom-helpers-on-laravel-5. So, each time you think you need to use that function or algorithm of yours, call it.