# Using VueJs build tools with Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-cli

I am using VueJs with Laravel and am using the Laravel's default installation of VueJs with their Laravel-Mix.

I want to use Babel, Eslint and Vue-Router all of which don't seem to come with Laravel's default installation?

How can I use the Vue Cli to handle all of this with Laravel or do I need to pull everything in separately, something that the Vue Cli was built for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Vue CLI is meant for bootstrapping SPA's from scratch where the main intent is a Vue.js powered website.

You are using Laravel here which always has everything bootstrapped so I guess it would be easiest to include it yourself. From my understanding Babel is already included.

If you want to also use ESLint and vue-router you can look at the Github repositories from the Vue.js CLI on how to set it up:

https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack

It is not that hard to set up.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to change my `laravel-mix` application to use `vue-cli` without having to lose the possiblity to serve my `*.blade.php` files with laravel directly. After a few days I got it working, hope it helps somebody else.

For reference, this uses https://github.com/yyx990803/laravel-vue-cli-3 as starting point. I originally posted it here https://github.com/yyx990803/laravel-vue-cli-3/issues/11#issuecomment-451154428 but will copy and paste the whole workaround here:

> After banging my head against it the whole of yesterday and today, I
>   got figured out how to still use it with a blade file.
>
> This is more a hack/workaround until it is better supported, but works
>   at my end. The goal is to still use my index.blade.html which has the
>   `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">` inside,
>   because I still need to use it until I build my authentication with
>   Vue. Also I wanted to get a HMRis beheavior work, so I could still use
>   `yarn serve` while developing instead of having to rerun `yarn build`
>   everytime I change anything. For this we will create our own `vuemix`
>   helper to replace laravel-mix `mix()` in our .blade.html files. I used
>   best practices described
>   [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28290332/best-practices-for-custom-helpers-in-laravel-5)
>   for this.
>
> So without further ado:
>
> We need to create 2 new files:
>   - `/bootstrap/helpers.php`
>   - `/frontend/hmr/hot`
>
> **helper.php**: this file adds a new laravel/blade/php helper `vuemix()` which we will use in our blade file instead of `mix()`
>
> ```
>
> if (! function_exists('vuemix')) {
>       /**
>        * Get the path to a versioned Mix file.
>        *
>        * @param  string  $path
>        * @param  string  $manifestDirectory
>        * @return \Illuminate\Support\HtmlString|string
>        *
>        * @throws \Exception
>        */
>       function vuemix($path, $manifestDirectory = '')
>       {
>           if (! Str::startsWith($path, '/')) {
>               $path = "/{$path}";
>           }
>
> ````
>     // check if HMR server is running via helper file 'hot'
>     if (file_exists(public_path($manifestDirectory.'/hot'))) {
>         $url = file_get_contents(public_path($manifestDirectory.'/hot'));
>         $main = '/app.js'; // only use this as path, because css, etc are already packed in HMR mode
>
>         if (Str::startsWith($url, ['http://', 'https://'])) {
>             return new HtmlString(Str::after($url, ':').$main);
>         }
>
>         return new HtmlString('//localhost:8080'.$main);
>     }
>     return new HtmlString($path); // return path without changing anything aka production
> } } ```
> ````
>
> after we have to also add our new "helpers.php" to `/composer.json` so
>   laravel knows to load it:
>
> `"autoload": {
>               ...
>
>           "files": [
>               ...
>               "bootstrap/helpers.php" 
>           ]
>       },`
>
> with that out of the way, in your `index.blade.html` file replace all
>   occurrences of `mix()` e.g. 
>       `<body>
>           <div id="app"> </div><!-- #app -->
>           <!-- Scripts -->
>           @stack('before-scripts')
>                   {!! script(mix('js/app.js')) !!}
>       </body>` with
>
> `<body>
>           <div id="app"> </div><!-- #app -->
>           <!-- Scripts -->
>           @stack('before-scripts')
>              {{script(vuemix('js/app.js'))}}
>              {{script(vuemix('js/chunk-vendors.js'))}}
>       </body>`
>
> you can do the same with your css files, it will then load app.js for
>   it, since `yarn serve` seems to pack the css into the livereload
>   app.js.
>
> **VERY IMPORTANT**
>
> one detailed which took me forever: if you are coming from
>   `laravel-mix` you probably only link your `app.js` and you are done.
>   but here you also have to link `chunk-vendors.js`, which for some
>   reason get's splitted and I can't turn off, because it's a feature. so
>   if you only had 1 line of linked JS, you now need two.
>
> Almost done. Now we just have to edit your `package.json` and
>   `vue.config.json` so it creates and temporary `hot` file when `yarn
>   serve` is started and also doesn't overwrite your index.php and
>   creates your js files without version hashes when you use `yarn
>   build`. because we have linked them above directly without these
>   hashed. the `hot` file modus operanti I got from `laravel-mix` as a
>   way to figure out if we are using `yarn serve` or `yarn build`. don't
>   hit me for it, I told you it's hackish ;)
>
> **package.json:** edit this scripts, to copy and remove our `hot` file `"scripts": {
>       "serve": "cp ./hmr/hot ../public/ && vue-cli-service serve",
>       "build": "rm -rf ../public/{js,css,img,hot} && vue-cli-service build --no-clean",   }` pay attention to **hot** on the build line,
>   it looks almost the same then the original line.
>
> now create `/frontend/hmr/hot` and fill it with this: 
>   `http://localhost:8080/`
>
> now `vue.config.json` add this lines, from [vue-cli
>   documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#disable-index-generation):
>   `////  Disable Index.html Generation   // disable hashes in
>   filenames   filenameHashing: false,   // delete HTML related webpack
>   plugins   chainWebpack: config => {
>       if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
>         config.plugins.delete('html')
>         config.plugins.delete('preload')
>         config.plugins.delete('prefetch')
>       }   },`
>
> you can also edit `indexPath` back, since index isn't generated
>   anymore while building: `// modify the location of the generated
>   HTML file.   // make sure to do this only in production.   indexPath:
>   "index.html",`
>
> And with this it should now be possible to use `yarn serve` and `yarn
>   build` with a "classical" laravel blade setup.