# Laravel 5.4 does not see changes in files

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel 5.4 on Windows 7 and Xampp 3.2.2. A few days ago Laravel started ignoring the changes I was making to the `.env` file. I couldn't find the solution so I reinstalled Laravel in a different directory and imported my *app* folder.

Now Laravel just stopped responding to the changes I am making to some PHP files. I added a function to the */vendor/illuminate/support/helpers.php* but I could not access it in the view. I deleted the content of the whole file and I could  still access the function previously declared in it.
I created a helpers file as instructed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28290332/best-practices-for-custom-helpers-on-laravel-5#28290359) but that too is being ignored.

Any changes to any views is immediately effected and `php artisan cache:clear` is not doing anything.

How is this happening? Does it even make sense?

Comment: delete all file from \storage\framework\views and clear cache using artisan

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm not having issues with views and `php artisan cache:clear` is not changing anything

Comment: have you tried dump autoload?

Comment: you should not edit any vendor files

Comment: Very true @AmandoVledder but the problem is the custom one is not working either.

Comment: @NimishaMolia yes I have bumped autoload after adding the custom file to  *composer.json*

Answer (score 1):

Laravel caches config values to improve performance.

You need to run either ***(recommended)***

```
php artisan config:cache
```

which will cache the new values you have, or

```
php artisan config:clear
```

which will turn off caching. I've had some experience with this causing errors though.

Comment: I tried `php artisan config:cache` several times before abandoning the whole thing. It was rebuilding the cache but I still had the same issues. I've just tried `php artisan config:clear` and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know it might sound rather stupid, but have you remembered to restart the server because you've edited the .env file?

Comment: Is that necessary when one is using Xampp? Is that not for those using the built in server

Comment: @murume yes, its something you must do every time you edit the .env file