# Laravel 5.5 not found class with correct namespace

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, namespaces, composer-php, autoload

My `./app` folder looks like:

```
+-- app
   +-- Classes
       +-- Events
          +-- EventBase.php
          +-- EventX.php
```

There's nothing secret with `EventX` file:

```
<?

namespace App\Classes\Events;

class EventX {
  // ...
}
```

`EventBase.php` represents a Facade that inside it I just try to instantiate an `EventX`:

```
public function someMethod() {
  new \App\Classes\Events\EventX;
  // ...
}
```

After this line, Framework throw an exception telling that class was not found:

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)
Class 'App\Classes\Events\EventX' not found
```

Even that:

```
file_exists(__DIR__ . '\EventX.php'); // true
```

I already had this issue before when trying to create Facades and solved by moving class file from his current directory and after moving back (yeah, I don't why but it worked).

Something tells me that this is an issue of autoload process, so I tried these command (but still not working):

```
php artisan cache:clear

php artisan clear-compiled

php artisan config:clear

composer dump-autoload
```

What can I do in order to investigate the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure, but a leading `\\` cause it perhaps? But, fyi, you can directly call  the class without its namespace since it appears inside same directory.

Comment: @Chay22 I know and also tried that, this is not a namespace issue even because there's no complex structure. Seems like an autoload problem

Comment: Well, it's hard then. Have you tried to delete vendor directory and perform composer reinstall?

Comment: "\" can't cause it because it's just an absolute way to set the class namespace. `\App\Classes\Events\EventX` or `EventX` has same output in this case...

Comment: @Chay22 packages reinstalled but the problem still as before.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with the php tag <?

```
<?php

namespace App\Classes\Events;

class EventX {
  // ...
}
```

> PHP also allows for short open tag <? (which is discouraged since it is only available if enabled using the short_open_tag php.ini configuration file directive, or if PHP was configured with the --enable-short-tags option).

[Link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the new namespace to your composer.json to the key "psr-4"

```
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Classes\\": "app/classes/"
```

otherwise composer can't detect your new namespace

Another approach can be found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28360186/6111545