# Laravel how to add function with boot()

Tags: laravel, search, public, boot

As you know inside the AppServiceProvider.php there is a public function boot().
Also i need my own function. This must works like boot. I need that function in everypage. That function just return some values for search-box. Its in the header section. Header values are in the boot function also. I can't figure out how to make global search.

```
public function boot()
{ 
    parent::boot();

    static::created(function(Request $request){
            // I don't know how it works. This could be completely wrong
        });

}
```

Am i need to add something like that? Any idea would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might be looking to create an helper function https://stackoverflow.com/q/28290332/5808894

Comment: actually yes. Helper is the solution. Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

You can create a provider yourself which will be initialised on boot.
[Laravel 5.6 Docs - Providers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/providers)