# how to make a function of this in php and then call it

Tags: php, laravel

```
$applicantAttr = [
            'name' => 'Taylor Otwell',
            'email' => 'vaibhav@coloredcow.com',
            'phone' => '123321',
            'college' => 'Sample college',
            'graduation_year' => '2018',
            'course' => 'Test Course',
            'linkedin' => 'https://github.com/coloredcow/employee-portal',
            'resume' => 'https://github.com/coloredcow/employee-portal',
            'form_data' => [
                'data 1' => 'Sample content 1',
                'data 2' => 'Sample content 2',
            ],
            'job_title' => $job->title,
        ];
```

how to make a function of this in php and then call it. After making a function then call it in another place.

Comment: What do you mean? I cannot understand your question.

Comment: do you want to wrap above code  into a function and return this array from function  ??

Comment: @MOHIT, Write here, what do you want to do?

Comment: Please first show your effort.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function in `helpers.php` file in your app folder

```
function getCustomData()
{
    $applicantAttr = [
            'name' => 'Taylor Otwell',
            'email' => 'vaibhav@coloredcow.com',
            'phone' => '123321',
            'college' => 'Sample college',
            'graduation_year' => '2018',
            'course' => 'Test Course',
            'linkedin' => 'https://github.com/coloredcow/employee-portal',
            'resume' => 'https://github.com/coloredcow/employee-portal',
            'form_data' => [
                'data 1' => 'Sample content 1',
                'data 2' => 'Sample content 2',
            ],
            'job_title' => $job->title,
        ];
    return $applicantAttr;
}
```

and call this function as:

```
getCustomData();
```

[For more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28290332/best-practices-for-custom-helpers-on-laravel-5)

Comment: I posted the same answer a few minutes ago but this only creates the same array each time. I think OP need to clarify what is expected

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: Is it that you looking for?