# NetBeans does not see a returning types of custom helper functions (Laravel, PHP)

Tags: php, laravel, netbeans, composer-php, type-hinting

I added my custom helpers file to `Laravel` project using `composer.json` like this

```
"autoload": {
  "psr-4": {
    "App\\": "app/"
  },
  "files": [
    "app/Helpers/helpers.php" 
  ]
},
```

And I checked, the same way `Laravel's` helper file is added to the project. This one: `\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php`

It is all working fine.

**But**

In my Netbeans type-hinting helper does not see returning type of the functions of my file. However it sees returning type of Laravel's helpers.

Why? How can I fix this?

*I tried Netbeans 8 and 10 - same problems.*

Comment: I suggest you to use phpstorm instead,, its same company made netbeans but netbeans its no longer supported with laravel updates

Comment: I tried, but did not like it. Not unless they will make a NetBeans like config preset. It is a torture to manually change every aspect of PHPStorm to make it similar to Netbeans and make a transition smoother. It is in their interest to do it. But they don't.