# Pass html into the second argument of @section

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have a master.blade.php which contains `@yield('page_tagline')`

I want to use it like so `@section('page_tagline', __('pages.home.tagline'))`

This will work if the translation does not contain any html, but it does.

So how can i use it like that without blade escaping it ?

Comment: Did either of the answers below answer your question or do you still need help with it?

Comment: @RossWilson your answer did in someway, i did not use it though. Will still accept it as a answer since it's the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to get around this would be to use the `HtmlString` class:

```
@section('page_tagline', new \Illuminate\Support\HtmlString( __('pages.home.tagline')))
```

You could then take this one step further and create a `macro` for the `Str` class or a [global helper function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28290332/best-practices-for-custom-helpers-in-laravel-5).

---

**Macro Example**

In you `AppServiceProvider` (or any service provider you want) add the following to the `boot` method:

```
Str::macro('html', function ($string) {
    return new HtmlString($string);
});
```

Don't forget to add the following `use` statements to the class:

```
use Illuminate\Support\HtmlString;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
```

Then you `@section` would look something like:

```
@section('content', Str::html( __('pages.home.tagline')))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
@section('page_tagline')
    {!! __('pages.home.tagline') !!}
@endsection
```

This way you can put HTML inside the tagline

Comment: I get that, but the point is i want to use it like so ```@section('page_tagline', __('pages.home.tagline'))```

Comment: Thanks @RossWilson I edited the answer with the un-escaped version

Comment: @frogeyedman I understand you want to use that version, but that is made as shortcut for the escaped version, so you can't.