# Is there any way to pass $domain variable on to the route() method by default

Tags: php, laravel

> I registered following routes on my `web.php` file

```
Route::domain('{domain}.project.test')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', function ($domain) {
        return view('welcome',compact('domain'));
    });

    Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);

    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home')->middleware('verified');

});
```

> I had to pass the domain variable into `welcome.blade.php` in order to pass it into `route()` method

```
<div class="top-right links">
        @auth
            <a href="{{ url('/home') }}">Home</a>
        @else
            <a href="{{ route('login',$domain) }}">Login</a>
            <a href="{{ route('register',$domain) }}">Register</a>
        @endauth
    </div>
```

> is there any way to pass`$domain` variable on to the
>   `route()` method by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a custom *helper function*, something like `droute()` below:

```
if (! function_exists('droute')) {
    function droute($name, $parameters = [], $absolute = true)
    {
        $parameters['domain'] = app('request')->route('domain');
        return app('url')->route($name, $parameters, $absolute);
    }
}
```

Here is a link on how to create [custom helpers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28290332/best-practices-for-custom-helpers-in-laravel-5).

Comment: Anyway, thank you for the helper method it works. But I am still facing some other issue relating default *laravel email verification* .

Comment: You're welcome, for the email verification problem it's better to open another question to leave this one clean..

Comment: It is related to the same problem.
I have got the following error because of  Laravel `route()` method. need `$domain` parameter

`Illuminate \ Routing \ Exceptions \ UrlGenerationException
Missing required parameters for [Route: verification.notice] [URI: email/verify].`

Comment: Yes but it's better to open another question, this is the way SO works.