# php pass Trait method to a variable that has function scope within the Class that inherits the Trait

Tags: php, inheritance, traits, php-7, laravel-6

I have a `Trait` called `TricksTrait` with a few string parsing and replacing functions that I use alot (most I read from the net and remove unwanted chars for domPdf || Maatwebsite Excel Html rendering engines) in my laravel `Controllers`.
I pass reference to the `Trait` by using `use TricksTrait` within my class `FilmController`.  The methods are used by referencing `$this` e.g. `$this->str_replace_json('The Fox & Hound')`.

The thing is I want to use the `TricksTrait` method `str_replace_json` within a view that is outputting html in a loop.  Using `$this->str_replace_json($variable)` in my view fails with error `Call to undefined method Illuminate\View\Engines\CompilerEngine::str_replace_json()` .

So I tried creating a function variable by passing the `TricksTrait` method to a variable within a controller class function:

```
class FilmController extends Controller
{
    use TricksTrait;
    public function downloadFile ($id) {
        $str_replace_json = "self::str_replace_json"; // gives error Class 'self' not found
    }
}
```

The `Trait` function reference fails as `Not found` for all the below:

```
"self::str_replace_json"; // gives error Class 'self' not found
"FilmController::str_replace_json"; // gives error Class 'FilmController' not found
"TricksTrait::str_replace_json"; // gives error Class 'TricksTrait' not found
```

How do I pass a `Trait` method reference to a variable that has function scope within the Class that inherits the `Trait`?

Comment: `str_replace_json` qualifies to be just a helper method now. You make new helper files that has these utility functions and autoload them.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28290332/best-practices-for-custom-helpers-in-laravel-5 looks like what you need. I don't really see the point of a trait if it's a "generic" helper.

Comment: I see what both you mean.  Certain functions within my TricksTrait it seems is a bit over the top.  Thanks Jeto and nice_dev. Or ServiceProvider.