# Laravel 8 Custom Helper function PHP Fatal error: Cannot redeclare functionName() previously declared in C:(patth)Helpers.php

Tags: php, laravel

I've a Custom function in App\Helpers.php. When I use the function in if statement in a blade file. I see error in Laragon error logs.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare CheckInvalidPlan() (previously declared in C:\laragon\www\projectname\app\Helpers.php:6) in C:\laragon\www\projectname\app\Helpers.php on line 6
```

However things works as expected. But why is this error causing and how can I fix it?

#Update

This is my function in Helpers.php

```
function CheckInvalidPlan($id)

{

    if (Plan::find($id) == null)
    {
        return true;
    }

}
```

This is my if statement in Controller.

```
if (CheckInvalidPlan ($request->plan_id))
        {
            return back()->with('invalid', 'Invalid membership plan spesified.');
        }
```

Comment: It would help if you shared relevant code files (namely the function declaration(s) and call).

Comment: Since first and second declarations on the same file/line, you're most likely requiring/including the file Helpers.php multiple times instead of using require_once/include_once.

Comment: Wrap your declaration in an `if (!function_exists('CheckInvalidPlan') { function CheckInvalidPlan .... }`

Comment: I've updated the code question. Please check.

Comment: how are you loading the helper file ? btw you should load it in the composer.json then dump the autoload

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can bypass this error by checking if your function already exists:

```php
if(! function_exists('CheckInvalidPlan')) {
    function CheckInvalidPlan($id)
    {
        if (Plan::find($id) == null)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

That's how Laravel helpers are declared:

```php
if (! function_exists('today')) {
    /**
     * Create a new Carbon instance for the current date.
     *
     * @param  \DateTimeZone|string|null  $tz
     * @return \Illuminate\Support\Carbon
     */
    function today($tz = null)
    {
        return Date::today($tz);
    }
}
```

However, a cleaner approach would be to understand why your helpers file is loaded twice.

It is hard to tell you exacly where the error could be, however you should inspect all your classes, the `app\Helpers.php` file should never be required manually. It should be autoloaded by composer, as explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28290359/3330212) (thanks N69S).

Comment: Thanks all. Wrapping function with if worked.

Comment: @Dilhan Glad it works! I see you are new to Stackoverflow, if this issue solves your problem, don't forget to validate the answer so other people with the same error can quickly find the solution. Have a nice day.